# TypeError: speechtxt() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, datetime, jupyter-notebook, voice-recognition, pyttsx3

I am writing code for voice recognition I am run the program, I am getting TypeError problem.

This is my code:

```
import pyttsx3 
import pyaudio 
import speech_recognition as sr
import webbrowser
import datetime
import pyjokes
​
def sptext():
    recognizer=sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening....")
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)
        try:
            print("recognizing...")
            data = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
            print(data)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Not understanding")
def speechtxt():
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    voices = engine.getProperty("voices")
    engine.setProperty("voice",voices[0].id)
    rate=engine.getProperty('rate')
    engine.setProperty('rate',150)
    engine.say(x)
    engine.runAndWait()
speechtxt("hello")
```

Output (error):

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [32], in <cell line: 28>()
     26     engine.say(x)
     27     engine.runAndWait()
---> 28 speechtxt("hello")

TypeError: speechtxt() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Add argument `x` to your function definition `def speechtxt(x):`

Comment: `def speechtxt()` takes no arguments. I assume you are missing `x`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't accepting any parameters in your `speechtxt` function, so when you try to pass one in, it errors out.

From the rest of your code, it looks like you want to replace:

```
def speechtxt():
```

with:

```
def speechtxt(x):
```

so that way it accepts the one parameter, `x`.